# lucene search query not working in solr4.6

Tags: mysql, solr

we have millions of records . Initially we used lucene to index data but due to OutofMemeory exception, decided to move data to solr. Below is the fields which we declare in schema.xml to perform indexing and seach operation.

```
 <field name="product"      type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="source"       type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="target"       type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="pos"          type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="company"     type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="deprecated"   type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 <field name="id"           type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="true"/>
```

We are using solrj api to craete solr query.

**Solr Query code:**

```
SolrQuery solrQuery=new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery("id:*_TB");
solrQuery.setRows(10000);
solrQuery.addFilterQuery(searchStr);//
QueryResponse rsp = httpserver.query(solrQuery);
```

In lucene following query was working in exact search,fuzzy search etc. when user type the phrase in UI.

EX:- New Brand launched

**For Exact Search in lucene**
searchstr = (source:"abc" OR target:"abc" OR deprecated:"abc") AND company:"tc"

**Fuzzy search:**
    searchstr = (source:New Brand launched~0.7 OR target:New Brand launched~0.7  OR deprecated:New Brand launched~0.7) AND company:"bb"

**Default search**

searchstr = (source:New Brand launched* OR target:New Brand launched*  OR deprecated:New Brand launched*) AND company:"cc"

Now in solr above query is not working. when user type the above "New Brand launched" phrase in UI its giving zero result.Sometime we are facing the problem of case sensitive  which was not in lucene.

please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have declared all fields of type string. string fieldtypes does not tokenize. do you really want this behaviour?
2. `(source:New Brand launched* OR target:New Brand launched* OR deprecated:New Brand launched*) AND company:"cc"`

    If you don't use double quotes around the text you want to search then it will not be a phrase query in SOLR. So `source:New Brand launched*` would actually be searched as 
   `source:New OR defaultField:Brand OR defaultField:launched*` 
    where defaultField would be the default field defined in schema.xml, and OR/AND will be used as per the default operator specified in schema.xml. Instead search for `source:"New Brand launched"`

Go through SOLR documentation for additional info.

Comment: In my application I want to phrase like search.   Ex: I want to search for "New Brand laun*" and should only get result as "New Brand launched", but as you mentioned this is search "New" in Source field and rest of the words is searched in default field. I want to get the behavior I get form SQL query for example: field1 like 'new brand laun*' or field2 like ''new brand laun*''. How can I achieve this behavior.